# Error: _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!entry"

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, file-handling

In lines 77-110, I am making a Button which changes the file.
In the program the user logs in with a specific line in the information file.
By clicking "block" or "unblock", it changes 'block/unblock', to 'unblock/block" for the specific line for the user.

I am using this text as 'information.txt' as a test:

```
user1 pass1 1234 2355 blocked
user2 pass2 4363 4254 unblocked
user3 pass3 2543 4396 blocked
```

The format of a line is:
username, password, balance, credit card limit, blocked/unblocked

My code: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/odefesahor.py

For example, if I logged in as us user 2, the user's card is unblocked.
If I log in a click on "Check if Blocked", then put "Blocked", it should change the line so that it says "blocked"

What should happen after clicking 'Blocked':

```
user1 pass1 1234 2355 blocked
user2 pass2 4363 4254 blocked
user3 pass3 2543 4396 blocked
```

However when I clicked on "block" or "unblocked" it cleared the whole text file, and came up with the full error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\work\test.py", line 96, in yes_select
    if items[0] == username_entry.get():
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3043, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!entry"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. Take the time to create a [mcve] specifically for this question.

Comment: That error is telling you that `username_entry` refers to an entry widget that has been deleted, or it could mean that you're using more than one instance of `Tk`.

Comment: Will do next time, sorry! It works now.